# ORA-00933 When trying to insert space followed by "n" Character

Tags: ant, flyway, oracle12c, ora-00933

I have the following SQL Migration Skript, but it fails when I try to insert the Varchar 'a n'. Upper or lower case is not important, the only important part appears to be that the ' n' are the last two characters. It works fine when executed manually with Toad and sqlplus.

The default flyway placeholder settings are unchanged.

Flyway Version: 2.3 and executed with Ant
Oracle Database 12.1.02.0

```
CREATE TABLE  TEST(
    TEST VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL
);

-- This works
INSERT INTO TEST (TEST) VALUES ( 'a b');
INSERT INTO TEST (TEST) VALUES ( 'a an');
INSERT INTO TEST (TEST) VALUES ( 'a nn');
INSERT INTO TEST (TEST) VALUES ( 'a n ');

-- This does not
INSERT INTO TEST (TEST) VALUES ( 'a n');
```

The complete stacktrace:

```
build.xml:38: Flyway Error: com.googlecode.flyway.core.command.FlywaySqlScriptException: Error executing statement at line 12: INSERT INTO TEST (TEST) VALUES ( ' n');
    at com.googlecode.flyway.ant.AbstractFlywayTask.execute(AbstractFlywayTask.java:331)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.EclipseDefaultExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseDefaultExecutor.java:32)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:424)
    at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.main(InternalAntRunner.java:138)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:445)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:879)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:450)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:192)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:193)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForRows(T4CStatement.java:1033)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1329)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeInternal(OracleStatement.java:1909)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.execute(OracleStatement.java:1871)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.execute(OracleStatementWrapper.java:318)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.dbsupport.JdbcTemplate.executeStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:230)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.dbsupport.SqlScript.execute(SqlScript.java:90)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.resolver.sql.SqlMigrationExecutor.execute(SqlMigrationExecutor.java:72)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.command.DbMigrate$2.doInTransaction(DbMigrate.java:243)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.command.DbMigrate$2.doInTransaction(DbMigrate.java:241)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.util.jdbc.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:72)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.command.DbMigrate.applyMigration(DbMigrate.java:241)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.command.DbMigrate.access$700(DbMigrate.java:44)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.command.DbMigrate$1.doInTransaction(DbMigrate.java:186)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.command.DbMigrate$1.doInTransaction(DbMigrate.java:135)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.util.jdbc.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:72)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.command.DbMigrate.migrate(DbMigrate.java:135)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:872)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway$1.execute(Flyway.java:819)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:1200)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:819)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.ant.MigrateTask.doExecuteWithMigrationConfig(MigrateTask.java:162)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.ant.AbstractMigrationLoadingTask.doExecute(AbstractMigrationLoadingTask.java:271)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.ant.AbstractFlywayTask.execute(AbstractFlywayTask.java:329)
    ... 16 more
```

Comment: This sounds like a bug in Flyway.

Comment: Please upgrade to 3.0 and try again

Comment: @AxelFontaine Thanks, with 3.0 it works! Could you post that as an Answer? (to document that as the solution)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed as part of 3.0